# I am facing an issue while trying to figure out points on a graph in LTspice. The point that I want to trace isn't appearing on the plot

Tags: ltspice, graph

For example, a simple low pass filter circuit plot(AC analysis). I want to find out the cutoff frequency, -3dB point. But it's not on the plot. I have tried changing the limits on the vertical and horizontal axes too, but in vain. What to do ?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you need to sweep higher than 1 MHz in your AC analysis.

Comment: Sweep to at least twice teh frequency of the 1dB point, i.e. at least 700kHz. 1MHz (or 2 or 5) would be good.

Answer (score 3):

You need to increase the Stop Frequency in the AC Analysis settings.
I generally use this setting for audio amplifier simulations, it should work for your filter as well:

```
.ac oct 500 1 1E9
```

That is octave sweep, 500 points per octave, start frequency 1Hz, stop frequency 1GHz.
If it takes too long reduce it to 200 ppo.
This will give you a very wide frequency range, you can then narrow it down by zooming (click and drag a box around the part you're interested in) or changing the axis settings.
Once you get the the ranges you want you can select the display window and choose 'save plot settings' under the File menu. Then the next time you run it you can select the window and press spacebar to load the saved settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the number of points evaluated per decade in the simulation window on the AC analysis tab

Comment: Increasing points per decade would only improve the resolution, not the range.